# Multiple errors when starting with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner with this so it may be basic.
I have included all the files, and try to add a button.
I see the button but when clicked I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

the code :

```
 <head>
            <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-sclase=1">
            <title>Create</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets/main.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet"  href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
 </head>




  <body>


        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="$(this).hide();">Clickit</button>


    <! --- scripsts                                                  
    <! --- bootstrap js files
     <script src="Bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <! --- my java script file
     <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Assuming this is all my code, I also get some other errors on consule like :

```
util.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:56
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

//and this one

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of favicon.ico:1
```

**EDIT :**

My project has folders structure: `Bootstrap->js->` inside `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js`, all under 1 folder which is my project.

Comment: The first error you have listed, refer to [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779148/javascript-jquery-is-not-defined-function-error) for your issue.

Comment: What version of bootstrap you are trying to use? For **Bootstrap 3** first try a page with the [started template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#template) using CDN libraries and then proceed to download and use they locally. Same is valid for **Bootstrap 4** with this [started template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template).

Comment: I downloaded all of them today so the latest versions.

Comment: @Irby not sure its the answer because as you see I already included the files as you may see. (?)

Comment: Please see edits.\

Comment: Have you try view page score and try click your link bootstrap?? If didnt show anything, so you need change your url.

Answer (score 2):

To get bootstrap, go to http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/. There it tells you what you need to use bootstrap.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can also go to http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/ to get the html tags to put in bootstrap.

I think that's probably the problem. Try with those.

**Edit:**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="$(this).hide();">Clickit</button>
</body>
```

I'm assuming you wanted that?

Comment: Not sure where is the answer, you point me to Bootstrap? obviously I already downloaded and included all the files as I said.. But thanks for the effort.

Comment: Look at the code snippet. I'm pretty sure that's what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found I was wrong with the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess it is too basic so some of you didn't see, my comment was wrong, it should be closed :

```
 <!-- jquery files -->
```

Now it works.