# org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: $ is not defined error taking coordinate screenshot with Ashot using ChromeDriver Selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ashot

I have encountered a weird problem while working with `AShot`.
`Ashot` works fine for whole screenShots but while selective screenShot it is **BAD**.
It throws error in **CoordsProvider** Class while getting co-ordinates of element.
am I using a faulty build or product?

```
public abstract class CoordsProvider implements Serializable {

public abstract Coords ofElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element);

public Set<Coords> ofElements(WebDriver driver, Iterable<WebElement> elements) {
    Set<Coords> elementsCoords = new HashSet<>();
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        ***Coords elementCoords = ofElement(driver, element);  //fails here***
        if (!elementCoords.isEmpty()) {
            elementsCoords.add(elementCoords);
        }
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(elementsCoords);
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public Set<Coords> ofElements(WebDriver driver, WebElement... elements) {
    return ofElements(driver, Arrays.asList(elements));
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public Set<Coords> locatedBy(WebDriver driver, By locator) {
    return ofElements(driver, driver.findElements(locator));
}
}
```

[image]
**Stack trace**

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: $ is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'OPTIMIZEQ-LTP03', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.130, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a81..., userDataDir: C:\Users\SHAILE~1.SIN\AppDa...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61006}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=localhos..., setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webdriver.remote.sessionid: f5a47b27537f019dacb73462732...}
Session ID: f5a47b27537f019dacb734627324a790
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:485) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]
    at ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.util.JsCoords.findCoordsWithJquery(JsCoords.java:30) ~[ashot-1.5.2.jar:na]
    at ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.coordinates.JqueryCoordsProvider.ofElement(JqueryCoordsProvider.java:13) ~[ashot-1.5.2.jar:na]
    at ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.coordinates.CoordsProvider.ofElements(CoordsProvider.java:21) ~[ashot-1.5.2.jar:na]
    at ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot.takeScreenshot(AShot.java:115) ~[ashot-1.5.2.jar:na]
    at ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot.takeScreenshot(AShot.java:132) ~[ashot-1.5.2.jar:na]
    at com.optq.main.util.SeleniumDriverUtility.captureAShotElement(SeleniumDriverUtility.java:563) ~[classes/:na]
```

Any help or Alternatives For Ashot are welcome,Please help me into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: $ is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'OPTIMIZEQ-LTP03', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.130, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a81..., userDataDir: C:\Users\SHAILE~1.SIN\AppDa...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61006}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=localhos..., setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webdriver.remote.sessionid: f5a47b27537f019dacb73462732...}
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to interact with the **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

### Deep dive

As per the documentation in [ReferenceError: "x" is not defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined) this error means there is a non-existent variable referenced somewhere within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). This variable needs to be declared, or you need to make sure it is available in your current script or scope.

> **Hint**: When loading a library (such as jQuery), make sure it is loaded before you access library variables, such as "$". Put the  tag that loads the library before your code that uses it.

As per the discussion [JavaScript/jQuery - “$ is not defined- $function()” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779148/javascript-jquery-is-not-defined-function-error) @Ketan mentions that this error occurs when *you have not made jQuery available to your script*, i.e. possibly the [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) / [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) / [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) haven't completed rendering the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

---

### Solution

In these cases there are 3(three) different approaches available to solve the issue as follows:

- The *jQuery* library is a single JavaScript file, and you reference it with the HTML `<script>` tag within the `<head>` section as follows:

  ```
  <head>
      <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  ```

  This goes out and gets the *jQuery* code from the source.

> **Note**: You do not have to include `type="text/javascript"` inside the `<script>` tag as this is not required in HTML5. JavaScript is the default scripting language in HTML5 and in all modern browsers.

- You can also [download the *jQuery* library](https://jquery.com/download/) and reference it locally on the server.
- You can induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) for the element's desired state either to be *present* / *visible* / *interactable*.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium: How selenium identifies elements visible or not? Is is possible that it is loaded in DOM but not rendered on UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165)

---

### This usecase

As you mentioned, the following line fails:

```
Coords elementCoords = ofElement(driver, element);
```

This method takes one of the arguments (last) as *element*, but while defining you seem to be treating it as a *list* of elements, as in:

```
@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public Set<Coords> ofElements(WebDriver driver, WebElement... elements) {
    return ofElements(driver, Arrays.asList(elements));
}
```

Seems some mismatch in argument types here.

---

### Additional considerations

You need to take care of a couple of things more:

- You are using *chromedriver=78.0.3904.105*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=78.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 78**

- You are using *chrome=79.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v79.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 79**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.14.0* of *2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z* which is almost **1.5** years older.
- Your *JDK version* is **11.0.2**.

So there is a clear mismatch between *JDK v8u111* , *Selenium Client v3.3.1* , *ChromeDriver v2.41* and the *Chrome Browser v79.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u241](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v80.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 80.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v80.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/notes.txt))

Comment: thanks for speedy help @debanjanB It is using 
`private CoordsProvider coordsProvider = new JqueryCoordsProvider();`
rest checkList is verified by me,I think that is Ashot team must change their Implementation.

Comment: I think @valfirst pointed us to the right direction in the discussion [Ashot is failing to take coordinate/Screenshot in chrome 79.0.3945.130 and selenium 3.141.59](https://github.com/pazone/ashot/issues/188) that instead of [JqueryCoordsProvider](https://github.com/pazone/ashot/blob/master/src/main/java/pazone/ashot/coordinates/JqueryCoordsProvider.java) we need to use [WebDriverCoordsProvider](https://github.com/pazone/ashot/blob/master/src/main/java/pazone/ashot/coordinates/WebDriverCoordsProvider.java)

Comment: yes but library is using this.
`private CoordsProvider coordsProvider = new JqueryCoordsProvider();`
I think that I can't change in JAR

Comment: Could you please update your answer ? The chromeDriver version is now over 90.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution here, https://medium.com/virtualmind-io/jquery-injection-for-selenium-automation-tests-f6121ea57993. Basically it injects jquery into the page.
So I followed the steps and created this method that i used before calling AShot methods and could solve this issue, leaving the code here:

```
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        if(!(Boolean) js.executeScript("return (typeof jQuery != \"undefined\")")) {
            js.executeScript(
                    "var headID = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" +
                            "var newScript = document.createElement('script');" +
                            "newScript.type = 'text/javascript';" +
                            "newScript.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';" +
                            "headID.appendChild(newScript);");
            WebDriverWait waitJQ = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            Function<WebDriver, Boolean> jQueryAvailable = WebDriver -> (
                    (Boolean) js.executeScript("return (typeof jQuery != \"undefined\")")
            );
            waitJQ.until(jQueryAvailable);
        }
```